# Parse error:syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, syntax-error

Where is a problem? Then I open .PHP on my /localhost show message "Parse error:syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in ..." 
maybe code is incorrect?

```
<?php
        if($_POST) {
            $name = $_POST['news_name'];
            $content = $_POST['news_text'];
            $handle = fopen ("z_padomi_ka_atmest_smekesanu.php","a");
            fwrite($handle,"<b>".$name."</b>:<br/>".$content."<br/>
            fclose($handle);
            }
        ?>

<script type="text/javascript">


    document.getElementById('com-form').action = "z_padomi_ka_atmest_smekesanu.php";


   </script>
    <form action = "" method="post">
    <p class="left"><label for="news_name"><b>Vārds:</b></label><br/><input type="text" name="news_name" id="news_name" value="" size="15" class="input big8"></p>
    <p class="even"><label for="news_text"><b>Pievienot atbildi:</b></label><br/><textarea name="news_text" id="news_text" cols="75" rows="3" wrap="virtual"></textarea></p>
    </p><p class="buttons right"><input id="add" type="submit" value="Pievienot" class="submit"><br>
    <li><a style="text-decoration: underline; padding-right:10px; padding-top:5px" href="pamaciba.html" target="_blank">Komentāru noteikumi</a></p>
    </form>
        <?php include "z_padomi_ka_atmest_smekesanu.php";
    </script>
```

Comment: Look at the end of the fwrite call, you forgot to end the function call and also the string is missing closing quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to close a string.

Change this

```
fwrite($handle,"<b>".$name."</b>:<br/>".$content."<br/>
fclose($handle);
```

To this

```
fwrite($handle,"<b>".$name."</b>:<br/>".$content."<br/>");
fclose($handle);
```

**EDIT**

You forgot a php close tag too :

```
<?php include "z_padomi_ka_atmest_smekesanu.php";
    </script>
```

To

```
<?php include "z_padomi_ka_atmest_smekesanu.php"; ?>
    </script>
```

Comment: and probably forgot to close the <?php tag on the bottom

Comment: Yep, I didn't see. I add it to my answer.